# Надо ли ставить проверку юзера на файлах AJAX, которые только делают выборку?

Tags: php

Надо ли ставить проверку юзера на файлах `AJAX` которые только делают выборку?

```
 if($_SESSION['check'] != sha1($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:  ../index.php"); 
    exit;
}

mysql_query(SELECT // ...
```

Comment: что-то ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да - надо. Если не делать, то можно будет левому пользователю получить нужную ему информацию.